# Mysql error Invalid use of group function

Tags: mysql

```
    select
    c.investor_id as investorid,
    i.name as investor_name,
    inv_typ.name as type_of_investor,
    (select count(*) from investor_users where user_id=iu.user_id) as num_of_investors,
    (select count(*) from task_logs where campaign_id=c.id) as num_of_task_logs,
    c.updated_at as updated_date,
    c.call_date as calldate,
    a.name as admin_name,
    c.id as campaign_id
  from
    admins a,
    investors i,
    investor_types inv_typ,
    campaigns c,
    task_logs tl,
    campaign_statuses cs,
    investor_users iu
  where
    c.investor_id=i.id
    and i.investor_type_id=inv_typ.id
    and i.id=iu.investor_id
    and c.campaign_status_id = cs.id
    and c.assigned_to_admin_id = a.id
    and c.campaign_type_id = 1
    and c.campaign_status_id = (select id from campaign_statuses having id=c.campaign_status_id and cs.code ='CLOSED') and c.assigned_to_admin_id = 46
    and tl.campaign_id = c.id and max((select task_logs.task_status_id from task_logs having task_logs.campaign_id = c.id)) = 9
  order by c.call_date ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a `max()` in the `where` clause:

```
max((select task_logs.task_status_id
     from task_logs
     having task_logs.campaign_id = c.id)) = 9
```

That is an improper use of an aggregation function.  Instead:

```
(select max(task_logs.task_status_id)
 from task_logs
 where task_logs.campaign_id = c.id) = 9
```

This glaring error was easy to spot, because it is so audacious.  However, your query would benefit from the following:

- Never use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper explicit `JOIN` syntax.  That is the proper way to express joins for two decades, so it is time for everyone to use it.
- Use table aliases so queries are easier to write and to read.
- Don't confuse the `having` clause with the `where` clause.  That subquery should have used `where`.